# Hadoop cluster Working

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

I have just started with Hadoop. My question may be silly for you, but it confusing.

My question is, If I have 10TB data and 10 nodes, is the data copied on all the nodes with 1 TB on each of them?

If it does and I submit a word count program. Does the MapReduce code run on every node? if so, does the reducer start on every node once the mapper is finished?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Hadoop.

The data distribution depends on your replication factor (`dfs.replication` in hdfs-site.xml). If the factor is 1, it means all data is stored just once within the cluster. 2 means twice, etc. So with replication factor 3, 10TB of data takes 30TB of space within the cluster. Replication factor above 1 also means that the same data block is never stored twice within the same server, but the copies reside on other servers.

In general the data is distributed rather evenly throughout the cluster, assuming the servers are identical. If, for some reason, it's not distributed evenly enough, you can run a Hadoop balancer process to balance the cluster.

The datanodes are meant to run the mapping phase with the data they have to avoid data transfers. So all the nodes are supposed to participate in the mapreduce. With replication factors above 1, I'm unsure how the work is distributed as the data is located in multiple places, but I'd imagine it's meant to be distributed rather evenly.

Comment: where the data store, on every cluster.  and one thing also If I have 10 clusters that mean map reduce code run on every cluster.

Comment: I guess you mean 10 servers in your cluster? Yes, if the nodes have a part of the data, they should run some of the mapreduce.